# JQuery UI Sortable Only Allows Drag to Top When Gripped from the Bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using JQuery UI and Sortable in order to drag portlets and reorder between a few different connected ".column" DIVs.

The problem is that in order to drag a portlet to the very top position of any of the columns, you have to grip/click towards the bottom of a portlet.  If you click/drag from the top of a portlet, you won't be able to place the portlet at the very top of a column...at least not without considerable effort moving the portlet around.

I have tried using the "cursorAt" attribute to force the cursor to the bottom, where dragging usually works, but it doesn't have the desired effect. Example: cursorAt: {left:  205, bottom: 5}

Here is a jsfiddle of the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/KxP72/

Otherwise, here is the code, starting with the JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
$(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column"
});
$(".column").disableSelection();
});
```

And here is the CSS

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder {border: 1px dashed #7E7F81; visibility: visible !important;            height: 200px !important;}
.ui-sortable-placeholder * {visibility: hidden;}
 #container {width: 100%; display: inline-block; border-top: 1px solid #3B3D41; border-       bottom: 1px solid #000; text-align: center;}
 #object_body {display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; padding: 200px 30px 200px 0px; position: relative; text-align: left;}
 div.column {float: left; display: inline-block; width: 437px;}
 div.portlet {display: inline-block; padding: 5px; width: 400px; min-height: 225px; background: #141517; border: 1px solid #111; margin: 25px 0px 0px 25px; color: #FFF; float: left; position: relative; cursor: move; box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #3D3F42; -moz-border-     radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
div.portlet img {width: 400px; margin-left: 0px;}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="object_body">
        <div class="column ui-sortable">
            <div class="portlet">
                <img src="http://druble.blob.core.windows.net/object/object_11151.jpg" style="height: 266px;">   
        </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                <img src="http://druble.blob.core.windows.net/object/object_11171.jpg" style="height: 266px;">   
        </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                <img src="http://druble.blob.core.windows.net/object/object_11191.jpg" style="height: 266px;">   
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column ui-sortable">
    <div class="portlet">
                <img src="http://druble.blob.core.windows.net/object/object_11161.jpg" style="height: 266px;">   
        </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                <img src="http://druble.blob.core.windows.net/object/object_19951.jpg" style="height: 501px;">   
        </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                <img src="http://druble.blob.core.windows.net/object/object_11201.jpg" style="height: 266px;">   
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove `float:left` for `.column` and `.portlet`, and make them both display:block instead of inline-block. To make them also aligned left you can change `#object_body` to `display:block` as well.

```
div.column {display: block;float: none;}
div.portlet {display: block;float: none;}
```

here I updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/KxP72/2/

With sortable container having `float:left` and/or `display:inline` makes it located at the very top, and images sorting becomes problematic within that bounds (as they are out of it). You may e.g add border to `.column` and see what it looks like.

Comment: Brilliant, it works. To think it was just a matter of a display block and the removal of a needless float. Thanks!